# Swift - Certain amount of URL Request per second without Timer

Tags: swift, session, url, queue, operation

How to send 3 request per second without Timer ?

```
    oq = OperationQueue.main
    oq.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    oq.qualityOfService = .background
    oqSession = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: oq)
    oqSession.dataTask(with: URL(...)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in....
```

Comment: Why can you not use Timer?

Comment: Because requests are executing in for{while{FuncWithCompletionHandler}}  . The func contains the session. I've tried with Timer with block and every loop += 0.5 , but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I don't think you are using `Timer` correctly if you are using it with loops and incrementing by 0.5. Please look up tutorials on how to use the `Timer` class.

Comment: I know how to use Timer. Before the for loop I declare `var seconds = 0.01` then before while I type the Timer with block so the while loop is in the block, then after the while block Timer.fire() and `seconds += 0.5` . It's not executing properly the timer like this...

Answer (score 0):

You could follow these steps:

1. Add a variable `lastRequest` of type `Date`
2. Set that variable to the current Date (by doing `lastRequest = Date()`) every time a request **has been made**.
3. Before a request can be made, compare `lastRequest` with the current date. If the difference is more than 1000 (I think that's a second), you can execute step 2. However, if it is less than 1000, you know that the last request has been made within the last second. Than execute other logic.

Answer (score 0):

Hi **Bogdan Bogdanov**,

Try this code, hope you help.

```
    class viewcontorlelr: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstStatement()
    }

    func firstStatement() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {

            self.secondStatement()
        })
    }

    func secondStatement() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {

        // Type your statue
        })
    }

}
```